# adding element to first position array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures

I was wondering why is it (n-1) in line 2? Shouldnt it be (n+1).[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDxnG.jpg)

```
for(var i=numbers.length; i >=0; i--){
    numbers[i] = numbers[i-1];
}
numbers[0] = -1;
```

Comment: Please post your code , not image

Comment: Please post your code , not image

Comment: Okay, I didn't know this.  Thank you for mentioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numbers here is your array.

as you can see they're starting the loop by initialized i to be the array's length.
Then it should be n-1

Let say you array is

```
a = [1,2]
a.length = 2
```

If you set a[i], for first time in the loop you will have: a[2]
a[2] is undefined.

Last element is a[1]
a[1] is 2

**to access the last element in array you should do a[a.lenght - 1]**

Comment: yup, understood now. it was a bit tricky, now it just clicks somehow. thank you .

Answer (score 1):

Array indexing starts from `0` and goes up to `n-1`. So in order to shift elements by `1` position,
If my array is `arr[]`,

element at `[n-1]` is shifted to `[n]`, `[n-2]` shifted to `[n-1]`, `[n-3]` shifted to `[n-2]` and so on uptill element at poisition `[0]` is shifted to `[1]`

Finally adding an element at position `0`.

So that is why the inner loop contains `arr[i-1]` assigning its value to `arr[i]`

Answer (score 0):

## Algorithm

```
for(var i=numbers.length; i >=0; i--){
    numbers[i] = numbers[i-1];
}
numbers[0] = -1;
```

## This is the array `numbers`

```
       0  1  2  3 <- Positions
0:    [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

## The algorithm works as follow

```
                    -> length = 4, so the algorithm will move the 4 to position numbers[4]
                    |
-> Iterations       |
|                   |
|      0   1  2  3  4  <- Positions
1:    [1,  2, 3, 4, 4] <- Move to right -> numbers[4] = numbers[3] 
2:    [1,  2, 3, 3, 4] <- Move to right -> numbers[3] = numbers[2] 
3:    [1,  2, 2, 3, 4] <- Move to right -> numbers[2] = numbers[1] 
4:    [1,  1, 2, 3, 4] <- Move to right -> numbers[1] = numbers[0] 
5:    [-1, 1, 2, 3, 4] <- numbers[0] = -1;
       ^
       |_ numbers[0] = -1
```

Basically, the algorithm is moving the values to the right.
The algorithm has `O(n)` complexity.

Comment: i understand now. very clever way to access shift elements using length value. thank you.